# Adding/updating information in a linked list that is contained within another linked list (C Programming)

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am a beginner trying to add information to/update information in a linked list that is contained within *another* linked list. My program is a simple contacts list, wherein the user can add contacts to the list and then add information to each contact (using the separate info list). I am getting a segmentation fault with my addInformation function, and I can't see what the issue is. Here are how the structures are defined:

```
typedef struct info {
  char *name;
  char *value;
  struct info *next;
} Info;

typedef struct contact {
  char *name;
  Info *information;
  struct contact *next;
} Contact;
```

And here is my addInformation function:

```
void addInformation(Contact *myContacts, char *contactName, char *infoName, char *infoValue) {
Contact *ptr = myContacts;
Info *ptr2 = ptr->information;

if (ptr == NULL) {
  printf("Error: No contacts added.\n");
  return;
}

while (ptr != NULL) {
  if (ptr->name != contactName) {
    printf("Error: Contact does not exist\n");
    return;
  }
   else {
      ptr2->name = infoName;
      ptr2->value = infoValue;
      ptr2->next = NULL;
      ptr->information = ptr2;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }

 return;
}
```

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code, it would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Add some abstraction over the lists. Please.

Comment: @Eugene Sh.: Right, so the basic idea is that you have a list of contacts. Each contact has a name and a list of information regarding that contact. Each piece of information contains the information’s name and value and a pointer to the next informational item for that contact. I'm trying to add a contact to the contacts list using an add-at-front algorithm, and then add information (whether it be a cellphone #, email, twitter handle, etc.) to that contact's information list using an add-at-end algorithm.

Comment: Please provide a simple, repeatable (compilable) example.

Comment: I hope you know all your `char*` assignments aren't copying string data. if `ptr` is `NULL`, then `ptr->information` will explode. You should do the `if (ptr == NULL)` check before any dereference. Other than that, your problem is in code not shown.

Comment: and `if (ptr->name != contactName)` is not doing a string comparison ... but maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My first reaction is that the memory for Contact->Information is not allocated. Hence ptr2 is NULL or garbage. @yano has already mentioned it.

I tried to write comments on the original code then decided it will be clearer to write up a new version with some comments. It would be even better to split the code into several functions.

```
void addInformation(Contact *myContacts, char *contactName, char *infoName, char *infoValue) {
    Contact *ptr = myContacts;

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: bad pointer to contacts storage.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(ptr->name,contactName) == 0) {
            // if it's a contact with the name we are looking for
            // then allocate and put info structure as a head of the list of info
            Info *newInfo = malloc(sizeof(Info));
            newInfo->name = infoName;
            newInfo->value = infoValue;
            newInfo->next = ptr->information;
            ptr->information = newInfo;
            return; // get out as we found our contact
        } else if (ptr->next == NULL ) {
            // there is nothing next, we are at the end of the list
            // allocate memory for both contact and information, fill it in
            // add the contact as the last element in the list of contacts.
            Contact* newContact = malloc(sizeof(Contact));
            newContact->name = contactName;
            newContact->information = malloc(sizeof(Info));
            newContact->information->name = infoName;
            newContact->information->value = infoValue;
            newContact->information->next = NULL;
            newContact->next = NULL;
            ptr->next = newContact;
            return; // get out as there is no reason to iterate more, it's the last element in the list
        } else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }


    return;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // Has to allocate the first contact. Otherwise the pointer management
    // will have to be different and addInformation function has to accept
    // pointer to pointer.
    Info info = { "nn", "vv", NULL };
    Contact myContacts = { "contact 1", &info, NULL };

    addInformation(&myContacts, "contact 2", "info 1", "val 2");
    addInformation(&myContacts, "contact 2", "info 3", "val 4");
    addInformation(&myContacts, "contact 1", "info 5", "val 6");

    printf("end");
    return 0;
}
```